# Which is the right path to place an initializer in a Padrino sub application

Tags: ruby, facebook, omniauth, padrino, subapplication

I'm working with OmniAuth-Facebook and initializing it in `mysubapp/app.rb`:

```
require 'omniauth-facebook' 

class MySubApp < Padrino::Application
  register Padrino::Rendering
  register Padrino::Mailer
  register Padrino::Helpers

  enable :sessions

  SCOPE = 'email,read_stream'
  ENV['APP_ID'] = '111111111111111'
  ENV['APP_SECRET'] = '11111111111111111111111111111111'

  use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :facebook, ENV['APP_ID'], ENV['APP_SECRET'], :scope => SCOPE
  end
end
```

I just want to know if this is the way you **should** work with Padrino. Is this the right place to put my initializers or, maybe, you can create an specific sub-application config.ru?

Answer (score 6):

Placing code into boot.rb for multi-app deployments, or in the apps app.rb is the correct place to put things.

If you like things looking cleaner you could create a new config/initializers directory then add the following to boot.rb

```
Padrino.require_dependencies "#{Padrino.root}/config/initializers/**/*.rb"
```

Here is the Padrino guide for [Special Folders](http://www.padrinorb.com/guides/development-commands#special-folders) which as a little bit more about loading or requiring additional paths.